# IOSharedDataQueue example

Tags: cocoa, kernel, iokit

Where can i found sample code for using IOSharedDataQueue ( i want to send data from user-space to kernel-space)?

Answer (score 0):

sending sporadic data betwixt userland and kernelspace is generally done via IOUserClient http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SimpleUserClient/Introduction/Intro.html

IOSharedDataQueue is a bigger hammer and would be to run a constant stream of data, like if you needed to push / pull audio or video data in realtime.

if you just need to get messages or notifications to and from the kernel, use a userClient...